# Details on "food products under bed"

Tags: ruach-rah

If food products were found under a bed, after someone slept (took a nap) on it, is there a way to render that food edible?
1) Is it possible to **rinse it 3 times**, like for food touched before morning netila [Mishna Brura 4, 14]?
2) And what if the food product was **not entirely under** the bed, is it possible to cut the part that was under?

Comment: Already saw https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31020/13791 but this question addresses two additional details.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83086/759